# Different C++ template typename definition means the same one?

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    int func(T a);
};

template <typename V>
int A<V>::func(V a) {
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2017, when I wrote the above code, the editor shows that `Function denfinition for 'func' not found`, and it suggests me to create a new one, which uses `typename T`. However, I can still compile and run successfully.

It really confuses me. Is that a bug in Visual Studio? Does `int A<V>::func(V a)` just the same as `int func(T a)` in class A?

Is it a good practice to write the same typename in all declarations and definitions?

Comment: The code is correct C++, and because it compiles and runs successfully, it's not a bug of MSVC compiler. A bug of the Visual Studio editor? Certainly, but I usually take the editor's error/warning messages with a grain of salt anyway, until I have actually compiled the code.

Comment: @chris It's an intellisense "error" displayed in the IDE. It is not a compiler error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, My bad, I thought it was a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that a bug in Visual Studio?

Yes, it's a bug in Intellisense (as shown by the fact that you can compile and run just fine).

> Does `int A<V>::func(V a)` just the same as `int func(T a)` in class `A`?

The class is `A<V>` (`A` is a *class template*) but yes.

> Is it a good practice to write the same typename in all declarations and definitions?

Perhaps, in order to maximise the clarity of your code.

If there's no reason to change the template parameter's name, don't change it.